# Multiple columns sorting in backbone

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have 3 columns that I sort individually. However, if I click any column's header, it gets sorted. If I click another column's header the first column is changed.

I need first column to remain unchanged, while other columns to be sorted based on first column.

Comment: You should post your code first if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js or another library with same APIs should already is in your page.

Underscore.js has a stable sort method for the collections -- [_.sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)